# OpenVPN - Cannot ping or ssh through vpn

Tags: networking, openvpn

I've set up OpenVPN 2.7, and can connect to the VPN just fine.

When I try to ping or SSH to another server on the private network through the VPN, the connection times out. However, tcpdump on the VPN host shows that the requests are indeed routed through the VPN. That said, traceroute on 10.0.3.228 does not show any hops.

Client side:

```
PING 10.0.3.228 (10.0.3.228): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
```

VPN Host side (tcpdump):

```
19:57:04.428931 IP 10.134.0.86 > 10.0.3.228: ICMP echo request, id 10780, seq 0, length 64
19:57:05.427092 IP 10.134.0.86 > 10.0.3.228: ICMP echo request, id 10780, seq 1, length 64
19:57:06.426985 IP 10.134.0.86 > 10.0.3.228: ICMP echo request, id 10780, seq 2, length 64
19:57:07.430971 IP 10.134.0.86 > 10.0.3.228: ICMP echo request, id 10780, seq 3, length 64
19:57:08.431029 IP 10.134.0.86 > 10.0.3.228: ICMP echo request, id 10780, seq 4, length 64
19:57:09.431041 IP 10.134.0.86 > 10.0.3.228: ICMP echo request, id 10780, seq 5, length 64
```

A route dump shows:

```
10/16              10.134.0.85        UGSc            0       34   utun2
10.134/16          10.134.0.85        UGSc            0        0   utun2       
10.134.0.85        10.134.0.86        UH              3       11   utun2
```

Any idea what I am missing? The VPN Host can both ping and connect via SSH to 10.0.3.228.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation I finally figured it out.

I had forgotten to enable forwarding in the kernel.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```